# How to DRY up Rails/ActiveRecord includes when using as_json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Assume the following relations:

`Blog` has_many `Posts` has_many `Comments` has_one `Author`

If I want to get all `Blogs` with all `Posts`, I could write:

```
Blog.all.as_json(:include => :posts)
```

However this will result in an N+1 query.

So instead I need to write:

```
Blog.includes(:posts).all.as_json(:include => :posts)
```

Which works as expected, but is not very DRY, especially when you have nested includes.

For example:

```
Blog.includes(
    :posts => {
        :comments => :author
    }
).all.as_json(
    :include => {
        :posts => {
            :include => {
                :comments => {
                    :include => :author
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

This problem becomes even worse when I need to query for this same JSON format in multiple locations.

I've thought about putting the `as_json` relations format in a class method like so:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::base
...
  def self.include_all_json_format
    :include => {
        :posts => {
            :include => {
                :comments => {
                    :include => :author
                }
            }
        }
     }
   end
...
end
```

Which solves the problem of querying for this JSON format in multiple locations, because I can then just use:

```
Blog.includes(
    :posts => {
        :comments => :author
    }
).all.as_json(
    Blog.include_all_json_format
)
```

But of course the `Blog.includes()` takes a different format for its relations hash, so this:

```
Blog.includes(
    Blog.include_all_json_format
).all.as_json(
    Blog.include_all_json_format
)
```

Won't work.

I could put the `Blog.includes()` relations hash in a second class method, but having two method declaring the same includes structure isn't DRY.

---

The only idea I can think of right now is using the `Blog.include_all_json_format` method mentioned above, and then writing a converter method that can turn that relations hash into the format expected by `Blog.includes()` (essentially just stripping out the `:include` keys) so it could be called as:

```
Blog.includes(
    MyConverter(Blog.include_all_json_format)
).all.as_json(
    Blog.include_all_json_format
)
```

But then it gets complicated when I want to use `:only` or `:except` in my `as_json` format.

---

How can I DRY these includes up, preferably only declaring the relations format once?

Perhaps there's some way to utilize named scopes or some gems?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could try [deep_pluck](https://github.com/khiav223577/deep_pluck) to DRY it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `as_json` method in your model

For example

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base

  def as_json
    super(:include => :posts)
  end
end
```

Then your controller should look like

`render json: @blogs`

**Suggestion**

You could use JBuilder, Rabl, AMS or other template library that would allow you to separate the response building out of your controller/model logic. Doing this would definitely DRY up your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Overriding the `as_json` would be the same as `Blog.all.as_json(:include => :posts)` though, correct? Therefore would still produce an inefficient N+1 query. I'll check out those libraries, thanks.

Comment: I think the whole point is that you should separate your "view" template from your controller logic. Something like `@blog = Blog.includes(:posts).all` then `render json: @blog` without calling as_json but still overriding it the way I showed you would be DRYing it up and prevent N+1 query.